# Trouble using AFNetworking for x-www-form-urlencoded POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm having trouble using AFNetworking for x-www-form-urlencoded POST. My code is as follows:

```
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = @"Bob's iPhone";
    NSString *code = self.textField.text;



    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer=[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"rw_app_id",code,@"code",uniqueIdentifier,@"device_id", nil];
    [manager POST:@"http://www.somesite.co/promos/" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    }];
```

I am getting the error: ***Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo=0x7f8f8bf49550 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8f8bf59910 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"***

I googled around to try and fix this and changed the request serializer with:

```
manager.requestSerializer=[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
```

No luck there. I have my server working fine for these types of requests using NSURLSession. But I want to get it working for AFNetworking. Could someone give me some pointers to what I might be doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

this should help

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

or use this one for `responseSerializer` instead of `requestSerializer`

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: I used the first one, and it works if my server echoes a JSON string. However if it's echoes anything else I get this error: Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: this should help:  AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[self setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];

Comment: Get this error now: Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7fc161450340 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc16165ea80 "Request failed: bad request (400)"}